# Unable to chain-access tuple types

Tags: rust

Given:

```
struct NameType([u8;64]);
name: (NameType, NameType);
```

I can do:

```
let def = &name.0   OR   &name.1
```

but I cannot do:

```
let def = &name.0.0   OR   &name.1.0
```

to access the internals. I have to do it twice:

```
let abc = &name.0;
let def = &abc.0;
```

why am I unable to chain it to access inner sub-tuples, tuple-structs etc?

```
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (ecf8c64e1 2015-03-21) (built 2015-03-22)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting brackets around your statement, e.g. `let def = (&name.0).0`?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman ah yes it works with brackets. But what does that mean? Why is chaining without bracket not allowed? The two step procedure above (which works) should be more naturally combined into a single step without brackets (which will keep growing as types become composed of more and more sub types). So could you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: The compiler recognizes "0.0" as a decimal number (I tested on rust-lang.org)

Comment: I think you can report that as a bug at `http://users.rust-lang.org/`

Comment: A [bug was reported](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `foo.0.0` will be parsed as having a number. This was [originally mentioned in the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0184-tuple-accessors.md), specifically [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/184#issuecomment-53498305):

> I'd rather not change the lexer to permit a.0.1. I'd rather just have that be an error and have people write out the names. We could always add it later.

You can certainly file a bug, but as a workaround, use parenthesis:

```
(foo.0).0
```

In my opinion, you shouldn't be nesting tuples that deep anyway. I'd highly recommend giving names to fields before you slowly go insane deciding if you wanted `foo.0.1.2` or `foo.1.2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers, I have also found out that a gap would work wonders :) So;

```
foo.0. 0  OR  foo.0 . 0 etc all work
```

is fine. Don't know how much it means but there is a way to chain it if somebody wants to though (without resorting to brackets)